# Cannot find the vmdk file to convert

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm tasked to convert some VMWare virtual machines (which I know just a little about) to Hyper-V. I know I have to convert the `.vmdk` file of VMWare to `.vhdx` format.

The issue is that I can't find the real `.vmdk` file of the virtual machine. There's a `.vmdk` file with the size of 150GB, but it's actually 1KB and contains:

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
encoding="UTF-8"
CID=975e71e0
parentCID=ffffffff
createType="vmfs"

# Extent description
RW 314572800 VMFS "CRM Module Server-flat.vmdk"

# The Disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.adapterType = "lsilogic"
ddb.geometry.cylinders = "19581"
ddb.geometry.heads = "255"
ddb.geometry.sectors = "63"
ddb.longContentID = "a06670da1183767e899ee15c975e71e0"
ddb.uuid = "60 00 C2 9a 81 64 05 42-5c 9f d9 9f e7 61 ed fe"
ddb.virtualHWVersion = "14"
```

I noticed `CRM Module Server-flat.vmdk` and looked for it but didn't find it anywhere.

What I'm missing?

Comment: You need to ask the person that gave this to you. We aren't able to find files for you.

Comment: Or simply you are not familiar with the subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have RDM vmdk file, which cannot be converted. Proof - https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1003199 . The vmdk file just points to physical device mapping and isn't a real virtual disk

You have to options:

1. Convert RDM to “normal” vmdk and then convert to vhdx. Here is a guide - http://www.vmwarearena.com/convert-rdm-to-vmdk/
2. If guest VM is Windows, you can use Starwind V2V in P2V mode for migration to Hyper-V - https://www.starwindsoftware.com/v2v-help/ConvertPhysicalMachinetoremoteMicrosoftHyperVServer.html

Comment: According to the descriptor, OP actually has vmdk. createType="vmfs" stands for vmdk. RDM would be "vmfsRawDeviceMap". In any case, he can use converter you've mentioned to convert vmdk to vhdx.

Comment: Thank you very much for the converter. The issue is that I don't have a separate Hyper-V server (as Starwind requires). I have to convert the vmdk files, install Hyper-V server on the machine and then re-create all VMs.

Comment: You can convert the drive inside guest VM to vhdx without Hyper-V server - https://www.starwindsoftware.com/v2v-help/ConvertPhysicalDisktoVHDVHDX.html